# как мне упомянуть автора

Tags: discord, discord-jda

мне нужно что бы сообщении пинговало человека кто отправил команду, но когда я пытаюсь проверить отправителя через message.author в консоли то он выдает undefined, и я не пойму как мне пингануть человека или хотя бы получить его ID
вот сам код

```
    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
    
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName(`contracts`)
            .setDescription(`интерактивная команда contracts`)
            .addStringOption((option) =>
            option.setName('действие')
            .setDescription('выбери что ты сделал')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
            {
                name: `взял контракт`,
                value: `взял контракт`
            },
            {
                name: `выполнил контракт`,
                value: `выполнил контракт`
            }
            ))
            .addStringOption((option) =>
            option.setName('контракт')
            .setDescription('выбери выполненный тобой контракт')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
            {
                name: `рыбный день`,
                value: `рыбный день`
            },
            {
                name: `Свадебный банкет`,
                value: `Свадебный банкет`
            },
            {
                name: `Кабельщик`,
                value: `Кабельщик`
            },
            {
                name: `415-й, я база, ответьте`,
                value: `415-й, я база, ответьте`
            },
            {
                name: `Шахта`,
                value: `Шахта`
            }))
            .addAttachmentOption((option) =>
            option.setName('доказательства')
            .setDescription('прикрепи доказательства что ты выполнил/взял контракт')
            .setRequired(true)),
        

            run: async (client,interaction) => {
                const action = interaction.options.getString('действие');
                const contract = interaction.options.getString('контракт');
                const file = interaction.options.getAttachment('доказательства')
                const Embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(`DarkGreen`)
                .setTitle('Принято!')
                .setDescription(`**ты ${action} ${contract}**`)
                .setTimestamp()
                console.log(action)
                console.log(contract)
                console.log(file)
                console.log("автор: " + Message.author)
                await interaction.reply({embeds: [Embed1],
                ephemeral: true    
            });


            const Embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(`DarkGreen`)
            .setTitle('Информация о контракте!')
            .setDescription(`@ ${action} ${contract}`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setImage(file.url)
            interaction.followUp({
              embeds: [Embed2]
            });
                }
                }
```